# Display post closest to today's date

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to display the post nearest to todays date but so far, no luck.

Lets say today is 18/10/2014, and i have 2 posts, **postA** has a date 17/10/2014 and **postB** has a date 21/10/2014, i want **postA** to be displayed because is nearest today.

The closest i could get to that result is with this code and i know its still far from what i'm looking for :)

```
$today = date('Ymd');
$date = get_sub_field('fixture-date'); // ACF Date Field

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'events',
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'meta_key' => $date,
'order' => 'DESC',
'posts_per_page' => 1,
'meta_query' => array(
    'key' => $date,
    'value' => $today
    'compare' => '>='
),
```

Answer (score 1):

## Get the closest post by date

Here is a function that can return you the post by the closest date.
I wrote you some comments to explain you the progress.

You can get only the post->ID or all the post object and do with it what you want.

```
function get_closet_post_by_date($date) {
    global $wpdb;
    // Check if there is posts before our $date
    $postA = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT ID, post_date FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_date < '{$date}' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 1");
    // Check if there is posts equals or after our $date
    $postB = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT ID, post_date FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_date >= '{$date}' ORDER BY post_date ASC LIMIT 1");
    /*
    *
    * Convert the posts dates and our $date to time; reduce the post dates from our $date and divide by 60
    * The result of this equals to the seconds before of after our $date
    *
    */
    $postAtime = floor((abs(strtotime($date) - strtotime($postA->post_date)))/(60));
    $postBtime = floor((abs(strtotime($date) - strtotime($postB->post_date)))/(60));


    // Check which of the posts is closer to our $date
    if($postAtime >= $postBtime) {
        echo $postB->ID; // Post ID
    } else {
        echo $postA->ID; // Post ID
    }
}

// Run the function
get_closet_post_by_date('2014-08-12');
```

Comment: Thank you Shibi for the reply. I will try it asap. Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

I did sth like that, it works for me:

```html
<?php
    $year = strftime('%Y');
 $month = strftime('%m');
 $day = strftime('%e');
 $argsi = array(
  'numberposts' => 1,
  'post_type' => $posttype,
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'date_query' => array(
   'after' => array(
    'year' => $year,
    'month' => $month,
    'day' => $day
    ),
   'inclusive' => 'true'
   )
  );
 $recent_post = new WP_Query($argsi);
    foreach ($recent_post as $recent) 
    {
      echo get_the_title($recent["ID"]);
      echo get_the_content($recent["ID"]);
    }
?>
```

it's important to use functions with 'get_'. $posttype can be simple 'post' or your custom post type.